# Access SIM card from code, I look for code eamples

Tags: android

I am developing a telephony tests on Android, I passed to work with Eclair.

I wish to know how can I work with sim card from code.
I write tests that testing a sim card on our platform 
I has a code that use to work on cap cake and has many errors when transfered to Donut/Eclair. Some apis missing etc. Please help me 
I would like to get links for code examples
What apis (relevant to Eclair ) should I use
What import to include at the top of my class
What classes should I use
...

Ilana

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is **[TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)** Class. Using this class you can access many information regarding SIM and Phone Hardware.

```
// Access IMEI, IMSI 

    private String imeiNumber = null; 
    private String imsiNumber = null; 
try
{
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    if( mTelephonyMgr != null )
    {
        imeiNumber = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
                imsiNumber = mTelephonyMgr.getSubscriberId();
    }
    else
    {
        imeiNumber = null;
    }
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
    System.out.println ( "IMSI Error : " + e.toString() );
}
```

Sameway, you can use other method of `TelephonyManager` class to access other SIM information like `getSimCountryIso()`, `getSimOperator()`, `getSimOperatorName()`, `getSimSerialNumber()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is the code `android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to access its location and a few more by typing `android.os.Environment`.

The you should look at the File class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html).